# Extracting a field from this script

Tags: javascript, sdk, splunk

I'm trying to use a field from this given snippet of code using the splunk javascript SDK (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2fask)):

```
// Search everything and return the first 100 results
var searchQuery = "search * | head 100";

// Set the search parameters
var searchParams = {
  exec_mode: "normal",
  earliest_time: "2012-06-20T16:27:43.000-07:00"
};

// Run a normal search that immediately returns the job's SID
service.search(
  searchQuery,
  searchParams,
  function(err, job) {

    // Display the job's search ID
    console.log("Job SID: ", job.sid);

    // Poll the status of the search job
    job.track({period: 200}, {
      done: function(job) {
        console.log("Done!");
        // Get the results and print them
        job.results({}, function(err, results, job) {
          var rows = results.rows;
         //I want the 'rows' array
        });

      },
      failed: function(job) {
        console.log("Job failed")
      },
      error: function(err) {
        done(err);
      }
    });

  }
);
```

The idea is to get the array varaible 'rows' so that after this snippet runs I can, say, run console.log(rows).

Adding a return below the line doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to access `rows` globally, you could declare `var rows;` in the global scope and use `rows = results.rows;`. You don't even really have to declare it, as long as you leave out the `var` keyword in your assignment.

Note though that said assignment is being called in an asynchronous callback; this means that it probably won't have executed immediately after `service.search(...)` returns. In some situations, asynchronous functions may call their callbacks a long time after the function returns. Therefore, if you want code to be executed only after the operation has completed, put/call that code inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I got about adding the 'console.log(rows)' inside the callback? I'm not clear on which part of the function is asynchronous and why.

Comment: I should clarify, my intention is to send the array 'rows' via a app.get(){[splunk api call]; res.send(rows);}, but I guess only after the asynch function finished executing

Comment: Your final callback is the `function(err, results, job) {...}`, which is an anonymous function that gets called at the end of all the async tasks. Right after `var rows = ...;` insert `res.send(rows);` and you should be good to go; the `res` variable is "captured" from the enclosing code

Comment: Asynchronous programming can be pretty confusing; check out http://callbackhell.com/ for a good explanation of how callbacks work.

Comment: Thanks very much :) I was reading their page before you replied, helped clear it up. All working now thanks very much :)